# npm throws ENOENT warnings on every install/uninstall/ls

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to do npm install on a Windows 7 shell for some js test development packages directly in a source code repository I cloned locally, in this case karma, chai and mocha..
I consistently get the following errors when trying to install, uninstall other packages.

```
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT, open '..SourceDirectory\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ..SourceDirectory\ No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ..SourceDirectory\ No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ..SourceDirectory\ No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ..SourceDirectory\ No license field.
```

`npm ls` also yields

```
npm ERR! error in ..SourceDirectory\: ENOENT, open '..SourceDirectory\package
.json'
```

I did pull the beta of the Windows npm upgrade from

[Windows Upgrade](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/blob/master/README.md)

because I was running into the file system path length error. I do not have a package.json dependency list located in the warnings' path. Is there a configuration step I missed?

Comment: Does your application folder have a package.json file? did you run npm init?

Comment: This was the solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 43):

Error message might be caused by missing `package.json` file. Change directory to your project's local directory, as an example (instead, use current working directory of your project):

```
cd /var/www/nodeBot
```

Following string will write `package.json`:

```
npm init
```

Answer menu-driven questions or use `--yes` to blast past them. Then press enter at the end to write out the file. You might see something like:

```
Wrote to /usr/local/bin/package.json:

{
  "name": "bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "twit": "^2.1.1"
},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`npm` is `node.js`'s package manager. `package.json` becomes `npm`'s configuration or settings file. The `twit` dependency was a program installed into my project dir. `npm install twit`

---

If a package.json file exists in your project's directory, you can use a text editor to fill in empty data fields that can also cause error messages.

Find the `description` field in the `package.json` file and manually add a description:

```
"description": "This is my latest disruptive technology app.",
```

In `license` field you can add `ISC` which basically means *open source project*:

```
"license": "ISC"
```

Comment: `cd /var/www/nodeBot` No such file or directory

Comment: that directory is just for example. replace that example directory with the current working directory of your project.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion...

My goal is to install a lib with npm with knowing a few implementation details as possible b/c I'm focused on using the libs.  When I've more time, I'll try to understand npm better...

In python, I can usually do `pip install LIB` w/o understanding the details.  I'd like to do the same with npm.

So... which dir should I be in when I run npm init?  Do I just run it once or do I need to run it each time I install a package?

Do I have to create a package.json for each project that I'm trying to install?  Where does package.json file (or files??) need to go?

Comment: after installing `npm install lodash`, for example, its latest version is added to the `node_modules` folder of your project, and a corresponding line is added to the `dependencies` list of your `package.json` file automatically. assuming you already initialized your project using `npm init` (which created `package.json`). also keep in mind that you can install packages locally and globally.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem, so i tried this commands. It works for me

**npm install npm@latest -g**

Hope it will work for you as well

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following command and this worked for me!!!

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: old one. now we need to give --force

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with your "engines" value in the parent package.json file.

For example, i had

```
"engines" : {
    "node": ">=6.10.0",
    "npm": ">=4.3.0"
}
```

I removed the "npm" key and it just worked (Scratching my head....)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue myself, all i did was to remove the `package-lock.json` file and now it works. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem but i was doing a silly mistake

if your npm is installed properly then problem can be confusion between developer to select the current directory to install .js packages.
Actually installing anything using npm requires Package.json file in the directory you want to install your package

eg: npm install abcd

now if you want to install  abcd package via npm make sure you are in the right directory using terminal

eg: my npm directory on my mac is

/Users/myMac/node_modules/assert-plus/package.json

so if make sure you are in directory

/Users/myMac/node_modules/assert-plus

select this directory via terminal and then write `npm install abcd`

Answer (score 0):

Had a same problem resolve by

```
cd [project folder]
npm cache clean --force
npm install -d
sudo npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch into the directory that you're working and then run:

```
npm -init
```

After running that, continue to press enter until you get to the end.

Comment: This is essentially the exact same as the accepted answer from four years ago, only it provide less explanation and slightly different syntax.